# Writing to a text file issue

Tags: c#

So I have the writing to a text file figured out (before it would erase the entire file) but now I can't actually write anything. If I press enter windows dings and the program does nothing. Here's my code:

```
        private void Input_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            string write = Input.Text;
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"Path.txt", true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(write);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it would be highly unusual to write to a file on key down....unless perhaps you are writing a key logger?

Comment: So how should I do it then? I've never done this kind of thing before

Comment: How should you do what?

Comment: Write to the file, I don't know what event to use.

Comment: @MitchWheat: and it appears that everyone should be *really ashamed* of writing one. Regardless of the purpose.

Comment: @zespri: I have no idea what your comment means.

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is handled specially by the textbox control. You'll need to subclass the textbox class and override the `IsInputKey` method. More information is available on the `TextBox.KeyDown` [event documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Most likely, you'll want an accompanying button and write your file from the button's `Click` event. But that's just a guess based on your comments.

Comment: ok, thanks! hopefully it works.